# mysql multiple indexed column query performance

Tags: mysql

Two Indexed Boolean Columns: `active|online`.

Out of 100000 users, 40000 is active and 12000 is online. I want to notify those who are only `online`. Which query should run faster? (only active users can go online)

```
Select * from users
where active=1
and online=1
```

OR

```
Select * from users 
where online=1
```

Comment: Your queries are not doing the same logical thing, and what determines what you run is first and foremost the logic.  That being said, just run both queries and see the difference, or run `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Does the first query select "those who are only online"?

Comment: I just want to get the online users

Comment: If only active users can go online, then the 2nd query covers the 1st. If a user is not active, he cannot be online? and if he is online, he must be active?

Comment: So just use the second query. If you need the users online, ask for them. The where is much faster if it only has to make one comparition and only has to go through one index

Comment: A composite index (online,active) should help